# Fluent Nhibernate Unidirectional mapping - ObjectNotFoundException after session restart

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Line has one Polygon, Polygon has many Point.
Can't load data in other session (after restarting the application) - Polygon.Points throws ObjectNotFoundException. 
When i update and reload parent entity in one session, all work fine.

Mapping:

```
public class LineMap : ClassMap<Line> 
{
    public LineMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Number);
        HasMany(x => x.Words)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse();
        References(x => x.Page);
        HasOne(x => x.Polygon)
            .Constrained()
            .ForeignKey()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class WordMap : ClassMap<Word>
{
    public WordMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Number);
        HasMany(x => x.Polygons)
            .Not.Inverse()    
            .Not.KeyNullable() 
            .Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Line);
    }
}

public class PolygonMap : ClassMap<Polygon>
{
    public PolygonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        HasMany(x => x.Points)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse();
    }
}

public class PointMap : ClassMap<Point>
{
    public PointMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.X);
        Map(x => x.Y);
        References(x => x.Polygon);
    }

}
```

Also i can't use bidirectional relationship because i have another entity - Word - that have one-to-many relationship to Polygon.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Mapping to

```
public class LineMap : ClassMap<Line> 
{
    public LineMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Number);
        HasMany(x => x.Words)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse();
        References(x => x.Page);
        HasMany(x => x.Polygon)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class WordMap : ClassMap<Word>
{
    public WordMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Number);
        HasMany(x => x.Polygons)
            .Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Line);
    }
}

public class PolygonMap : ClassMap<Polygon>
{
    public PolygonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        HasMany(x => x.Points)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse();
    }
}

public class PointMap : ClassMap<Point>
{
    public PointMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.X);
        Map(x => x.Y);
        References(x => x.Polygon);
    }

}
```

And added to domain code:

```
public virtual Polygon Polygon
        {
            get
            {
                if (Polygons.Count == 0) return null;
                return Polygons[0];
            }
            set
            {
                if(Polygons.Count == 0)
                {
                    Polygons.Add(value);
                    return;
                }
                Polygons[0]=(value);
            }
        }
```